# properties file search and replace

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I've got two properties files and I'd like to replace key/value pairs in File A with any matching key/value entries in File B. File A will have more entries than File B - it's not expected that the two files will have the exact same number of entries. Also, File B might have entries which are not included in File A.

As an example:

```
File A
"GB" = "United Kingdom";
"SE" = "Sweden";
"BR" = "Brazil";
"FR" = "France";
"ES" = "Spain";
"DE" = "Germany";

File B
"GB" = "Regno Unito";
"SE" = "Svezia";
"BR" = "Brasile";
"BR" = "Brasile";
"CL" = "Cile";

Desired Result
"GB" = "Regno Unito";
"SE" = "Svezia";
"BR" = "Brasile";
"FR" = "France";
"ES" = "Spain";
"DE" = "Germany";
"CL" = "Cile";
```

Is it possible to execute this search and replace using bash?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: I hadn't really tried a solution myself. Was just asking for guidance in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk -F " = " 'FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2; next } $1 in array { sub ($2, array[$1]) }1' fileb filea
```

Results:

```
"GB" = "Regno Unito";
"SE" = "Svezia";
"BR" = "Brasile";
"FR" = "France";
"ES" = "Spain";
"DE" = "Germany";
```

---

***EDIT:***

You can simply delete the array elements after a substitution has occurred. Then at the end of the script, print out what's left:

```
awk -F " = " 'FNR==NR { array[$1]=$2; next } $1 in array { sub ($2, array[$1]); delete array[$1] }1; END { for (i in array) print i FS array[i] }' fileb filea
```

Results:

```
"GB" = "Regno Unito";
"SE" = "Svezia";
"BR" = "Brasile";
"FR" = "France";
"ES" = "Spain";
"DE" = "Germany";
"CL" = "Cile";
```

Comment: **+1**.  It seems that every awk post I see of yours includes `FNR==NR`.  :-)

Comment: @ghoti: Thanks mate. You're right, it's my favorite construct and it's pretty easy on the eyes too :-)

Comment: I'll just point out that the nothing in your answer is particularly gawkish. A far as I can tell, it should work perfectly fine in non-GNU awk.

Comment: This script _nearly_ does exactly what I need. However, the files that I have to work with have the following output from file -I: "Localizable.strings: text/html; charset=utf-16le". Is there any way to get awk to read files like this. I tried converting the files to UTF-8, but that results in a corrupted file.

Comment: Cheers Steve - posted a follow up question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13186293/awk-and-file-encodings. I didn't really want to pollute this question with character encodings, so I thought it best to create a new question.

Comment: @seanoshea: An excellent idea. My knowledge of character encoding is a little limited. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: @seanoshea: Just wondering if you have seen my comment under your new question?

Comment: @steve yep. turns out I wasn't using iconv correctly. All sorted now. Thanks again.

Comment: @steve - edited my question. It it possible to include an entry which is in File B, but not in File A in the desired output?

Comment: @seanoshea: Please see the edit. It should do exactly what you're looking for, and it will avoid printing the duplicate entries in fileb. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

The following bash-only script will spit out the results you're asking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Identify our files. If you want, test for their existence before proceeding.
fileA="$1"
fileB="$2"

# Define an associated array
declare -A countries

# Read our initial data
while read cc junk name; do
 if [[ -n "$cc" ]]; then
   countries["$cc"]="$name"
 fi
done < "$fileA"

# Overwrite array elements with updated values
while read cc junk name; do
 if [[ -n "$cc" ]]; then
   countries["$cc"]="$name"
 fi
done < "$fileB"

# Print the results
for cc in "${!countries[@]}"; do
  echo "$cc = ${countries[$cc]}"
done
```

The results won't be in exactly the same order, but I suspect that isn't important.  If it is, you can create an additional array whose index is a counter, then instead of the final `for cc in ...`, you can simply walk through that array to get the `$countries` indices in the right order.  Let me know if that's important and you can't figure it out.

I only post this here because you asked for a bash solution.  Steve's `awk` script is much more succinct, and probably a lot faster.  (Just guessing.  It probably isn't even worth the time to benchmark it.)